# Cannot find "manage my add-ins"

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js

I just bought an Office 365 family account, and installed Excel on my Windows.

However, I cannot find "manayge my add-ins" where we could upload an xml for testing. I have been always using excel online to test my xml/addin.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side-loading on Windows is a bit different. You need to setup a network share and store your manifest file there. Once you configure your client, it will automatically start picking up manifest files from that directory.

See [Sideload Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins#specify-the-shared-folder-as-a-trusted-catalog) for more complete details on this process.

Comment: Wow... I used to do this often, but for long time, I have not used Excel for Windows, I totally forgot it...

Comment: That is understandable, side-loading can be pretty confusing given that every platform has it's own method. My recommended method is to sign up for a Developer Tenant from https://dev.office.com and upload your manifest into that tenant's catalog. This allows you to upload once and get it deployed everywhere you need to test.